# Tesseract OCR is unable to find custom .traineddata file

Tags: javascript, node.js, tesseract

I'm trying to use the "node-tesseract-ocr" module with electron to perform some basic image-to-text translations, but I'm having issues that I cannot seem to figure out, for the life of me. I'm using the exact same code as provided in the example (seen here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-tesseract-ocr), except I've changed the "lang" parameter for the configuration to the name of my custom .traineddata file. I've installed Tesseract manually alongside this, and have set the PATH variables for Tesseract ("C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR" and "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata"), and have placed the .traineddata file inside of the \tessdata folder.

Here's the error:

```
Command failed: tesseract "./screen.png" stdout -l mc --oem 1 --psm 3
Error opening data file C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/mc.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'mc'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.
```

I have no idea why the slashes swap midway through the path to the .traineddata file; I'm assuming this is the issue, but I have no idea how to fix this, as it seems to be an issue with Tesseract itself.

Did I install an incorrect version or something? (I installed Tesseract using "tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.2.0.20220712.exe" from "https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/", as suggested by "https://medium.com/quantrium-tech/installing-and-using-tesseract-4-on-windows-10-4f7930313f82").

Everything works perfectly fine when using "eng" as the language, except the characters are not always read properly (since I'm attempting to read characters from a game, rather than handwriting/a standard English font, which is why I need the custom .traineddata file to work).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the installation from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki and it seems to work now. Not sure why the other installation was bugged, but oh well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).